# Swift - PHP : Textfield value sent over to PHP is received as null

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift

I hope you all are doing well and staying safe! :)

I am new to iOS programming. I am trying to post values from a textfield to a MYSQL Database. As a first step, I tried to just print the values received on the PHP end.

The values are printed on the Swift end but on the PHP end, an empty string(null) is received. Could you please help and let me know why the string received on PHP end is null? Please help! I am stuck and unsure of what to do next.

I have tried retrieving values from the database and that code works perfectly fine.

Thanks in advance!

EDITED:
This has been now fixed. The correct code is below -

Swift Code:

```
struct DatatoPost : Codable{
    
    var name : String
    
    init() {
        
        name = "Empty String"
        
    }
    
}

var myDatatoPost = DatatoPost()

//Protocol created for this structure so that it can be applied to multiple class (View Controllers) that create a delegate for it(ManageDataDelegate)
protocol ManageDataDelegate {
    
    func updateViewController(_ myManager : ManageData, saveOutputData: OutputData)
    func didFailError(error : Error)
    
}


/* what action is expected to be taken on data reached through PHP file*/
struct ManageData {

    var delegate : ManageDataDelegate?
    var data : Data

    init() {
        data = Data()
    }
    
    //create POST URL based on function - this is the URL to post data to the backend.
    mutating func postPHPData(){
        
        let urlPostString = myConstant.baseURL + myConstant.postPHPValue
        print(urlPostString)
        
        performPostOperation(urlPostString)
        
    }
    
    
    //Steps to create URL and other related objects - prepare data for parsing.
    mutating func performPostOperation(_ urlPostString : String) {
        
        //1. Create URL
        if let url = URL(string: urlPostString){
            
            //Create request variable
            var request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            
            do{
             
                
                let params : [String : Encodable] = ["name": myDatatoPost.name]
                data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .init())
                
                let body = Data(data).base64EncodedData()
                
                
                print("Data is: ")
                let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print(dataString)
            
                
                request.httpBody = body
                let requestString = String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8)
                print("Request String is:")
                print(requestString)
                
                
                
                //2. Create URLSession
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                
                //3. Give the session a task
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: handlePOST(data:response:error:))
                
                //4. Start the session
                task.resume()
            
                
            }catch{
                
               print(error)
                
            }
            
            
        
        }
    
        
    }
    
    
    //Function that lists the activities that need to be completed in the URL session - GET Data.
    func handlePOST(data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error: Error?){
    
        if error != nil {
            
            delegate?.didFailError(error: error!)
            print("error is")
            print(error!)
            return
            
        }
        
        if let safeData = data{
            
            let dataString = String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8)
            print(dataString)
            
           
            
        }
        
        print(response)
        
    
    }
    
    
    
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
 
echo "we are here";

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");

echo "we are here again";

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ";
}

$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),TRUE);

$decoded = base64_decode($postdata);

echo "decoded!";
print_r($decoded,true);
//this value is not printed

echo "postdata";
echo $postdata->name;
//this value is not printed

$name= $postdata["name"];
echo "Name";
echo $postdata["name"];
//this value is not printed

echo "Base 64";
echo base64_decode($postdata["name"]);
echo base64_decode($postdata->name);
//This value is not printed

if (empty($postdata["name"])){

    echo "String is empty";
    //this is printed

}


if (empty($postdata->name)){

    echo "String is empty";
    //This is printed

}


echo "Its done";

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You have `Data(data).base64EncodedData()` and do not `base64_decode` in php. Maybe try without base64?

Comment: So, I see that you have base64_decode further down the code but I think you need to do it earlier. I would try this `json_decode(base64_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")),TRUE);`

Comment: Hi Marcel, Thank you so much for your help! I tried replacing with "$decoded = json_decode(base64_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")),TRUE);" but it hasn't changed the outcome yet - the strings are still empty on PHP end. Please help!

Comment: `print_r($decoded,true);` will not print anything, it redirects the output to return value. So if you use `true` as your second argument to `print_r`, you should take its return value. `$ret = print_r($decoded, true); echo $ret;`. Or simply just `print_r($decoded);` without second argument.

Comment: The better way to dump the data is using `var_dump($decoded);`, in case the data is an "empty string" or `null` or `false`, `var_dump` will still show you what exactly it is. Unlike `print_r("");` and `print_r(null);` and `print_r(false);` which result in the same thing (no output).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Ammar!! :) I tried var_dump and "NULL\n" is printed out. Could someone please help and tell me why null is received on the PHP end when I see the data on the Swift end? Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: By the way, you haven't shown it here, but when you do get to inserting values into your database, make sure you don't just build a SQL string inserting the values into it (which is what practically all first-time attempts do), but rather [bind values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to `?` placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified your request’s `Content-Type` to be `application/json`. So it should be JSON, free of base64 encoding. The only time you should use base64-encoding is if you are trying to send binary data in JSON. (And even then, in that case, we would reach for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, not `application/json` request.)

Anyway, to send JSON request and parse JSON response:

```swift
protocol ManageDataDelegate: class {
    func didFailError(error: Error)
    func didReceiveResponse(object: Any)
}

/* what action is expected to be taken on data reached through PHP file*/

struct ManageData {
    weak var delegate: ManageDataDelegate? // delegates should always be weak to avoid strong reference cycle; obviously `ManageDataDelegate` must be class protocol

    //create POST URL based on function - this is the URL to post data to the backend.
    func postPHPData(name: String) {
        let urlPostString = URL(string: MyConstant.baseURL)!.appendingPathComponent(MyConstant.postPHPValue)
        print(urlPostString)

        performPostOperation(urlPostString, name: name)
    }

    //Steps to create URL and other related objects - prepare data for parsing.
    func performPostOperation(_ url: URL, name: String) {
        //Create request variable
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        do {
            let params = ["name": name]
            let body = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params)

            // 1. for diagnostic purposes, let's look at the JSON
            if let json = String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("JSON is:", json)
            }

            request.httpBody = body

            //2. Create URLSession
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            //3. Give the session a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: handlePOST(data:response:error:))

            //4. Start the session
            task.resume()

            //5. If creating a URLSession locally, make sure to invalidate it when the request is done or else you will leak memory; better, create one `URLSession` and reuse it for all of your requests (and then you don't need/want to invalidate it)
            session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    enum ManageDataError: Error {
        case unknownError(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?)
        case notJsonResponse(String)
    }

    //Function that lists the activities that need to be completed in the URL session - GET Data.
    func handlePOST(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
        guard let responseData = data, error == nil else {
            let error = error ?? ManageDataError.unknownError(data, response, error)
            delegate?.didFailError(error: error)
            print("error is")
            print(error)
            return
        }

        if let object = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) {
            delegate?.didReceiveResponse(object: object)
        } else if let string = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8) {
            delegate?.didFailError(error: ManageDataError.notJsonResponse(string))
        } else {
            delegate?.didFailError(error: ManageDataError.unknownError(data, response, error))
        }

        print(response ?? "No response")
    }
}
```

There are a variety of refinements buried in the above (if creating a session, you must invalidate it when finished; passing responses to the delegate; making sure delegate reference is weak to avoid strong reference cycles; etc.), but hopefully this illustrates the idea: No base64-encoding is needed or desired with JSON requests.

---

Note, you have specified the request’s `Accept` to also be `application/json` so I would make sure it did precisely that:

```php
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/json");

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    $result = [
        "success" => false,
        "message" => "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error()
    ];
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    exit();
}

$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

if (isset($postdata["name"])) 
{
    $result = [
        "success" => true,
        "name" => $postdata["name"]
    ];
}
else
{
    $result = [
        "success" => false,
        "message" => "'name' not found",
        "postdata" => $postdata
    ];
}

echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// Close connections

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

So, this parses the JSON and checks for `name`, but returning a JSON response, which is what the client was looking for.

---

There are other refinements I would suggest (e.g. I would use `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` rather than `JSONSerialization`; not create new `URLSession` for every request; usually a “network controller” like this would be a reference type so that you can use the same one wherever needed; I would use a framework such as Laravel in the server code, etc.), but I did not want to stray too far from the question at hand.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Rob! :)